Powerpoint cannot find Dim attribute
I have a powerpoint with one slide, one shape (textbox) containig the string "Hello There". Originally the text is set to purple.
Then in the animation upon entry (on click on the page) i change the text to green.  When I click again (i am done) i change the
text to yellow (that is the Dim attribute on the event).  I also added "Until Next Click" on the timing tab.
This works as expected when I run the slide show.
I now have a vba routine.  I want that routine to find the yellow phrase.  I have code that looks like this:
Sub ReadSlidesX()
filePath = gsTextPath
fileNumber = FreeFile
Open filePath & "X" For Output As #fileNumber
slideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
Print #fileNumber, "Slides: " & slideCount
slideCount = 1                                                          'for testing just look at the first slide
Set mstRec = New mstRecord
For slideCurrent = 1 To slideCount
Set Ppt_Slide = ActivePresentation.Slides(slideCurrent)
Print #fileNumber, "======== NEW SLIDE ====================="
Print #fileNumber, "Slide: " & slideCurrent
Print #fileNumber, "Slide ID: " & Ppt_Slide.SlideID
Print #fileNumber, "Slide Name: " & Ppt_Slide.Name
Print #fileNumber, "Slide Number: " & Ppt_Slide.SlideNumber
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(0) & "Slide Width: ", Ppt_Slide.CustomLayout.Width)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(0) & "Slide Height: ", Ppt_Slide.CustomLayout.Height)
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(0) & "slide Foreground Fill: ", Ppt_Slide.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB)
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(0) & "Slide Background Fill: ", Ppt_Slide.Background.Fill.BackColor.RGB)
Print #fileNumber, "Slide Interactive Sequences: " & CStr(Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Count)
sX = "(no shapes)"
If Ppt_Slide.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
sX = CStr(Ppt_Slide.Shapes.Count)
End If
Print #fileNumber, "Slide Shapes: " & sX
If Ppt_Slide.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
For lShape = 1 To Ppt_Slide.Shapes.Count
With Ppt_Slide.Shapes(lShape)
Print #fileNumber, "Shape: " & lShape
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape ID: " & .Id
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape Name: " & .Name
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape Title: " & .Title
sX = ShapeTypeName(.Type)
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape   Type: " & .Type & " (" & sX & ")"
Call PrintTF(fileNumber, Space(4) & "Visible: ", .Visible)
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape Background: Color: ", .Fill.BackColor.RGB)
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape Foreground Color: ", .Fill.ForeColor.RGB)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape  Width: ", .Width)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape Height: ", .Height)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape   Left: ", .Left)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape    Top: ", .Top)
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Font"
On Error Resume Next:
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Font Name: " & .TextEffect.FontName:
On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next
sX = FixText(.TextEffect.Text, True)
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Text " & sX
On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next:
sX = "true"
If .TextEffect.FontBold = True Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Font is Bold":
Else
sX = "false"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next:
sX = "true"
If .TextEffect.FontItalic = True Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Font is Italic":
Else
sX = "false"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next:
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Font Size: " & .TextEffect.FontSize:
On Error GoTo 0
If .HasTextFrame = True Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Frame 1"
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Top Margin: ", .TextFrame.MarginTop)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Right Margin: ", .TextFrame.MarginRight)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Bottom Margin: ", .TextFrame.MarginBottom)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Left Margin: ", .TextFrame.MarginLeft)
' Get Horizontal Alignment
Select Case .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor
Case ppAlignLeft
    horizAlign = "Left"
Case ppAlignCenter
    horizAlign = "Center"
Case ppAlignRight
    horizAlign = "Right"
Case ppAlignJustify
    horizAlign = "Justify"
Case Else
    horizAlign = "Unknown"
End Select
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Horizontal Alignment: " & Trim(Str(.TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor)) & " (" & horizAlign & "}"
If .TextFrame.HasText = True Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Text Range"
Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Range Text: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Text
Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Range Start: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Start
Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Range Length: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Length
Print #fileNumber, Space(12) & "Font"
Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Font Name: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name
Call PrintTF(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Bold: ", .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold)
Call PrintTF(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Italic: ", .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic)
Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Size " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Color: ", .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB)
sX = "(no paragraphs)"
If .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count > 0 Then
    sX = CStr(.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count)
End If
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Paragraphs: " & sX
For lParagraph = 1 To .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
    Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Paragraph: " & CStr(lParagraph) & " < 1<<<<<<<<<<<<"
    sX = .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Text
    bX = False
    While (bX = False)
        bX = True
        iX = Len(sX)
        If iX > 0 Then
            If Mid(sX, iX, 1) = vbCrLf Or Mid(sX, iX, 1) = vbCr Or Mid(sX, iX, 1) = vbLf Then
                If iX > 1 Then
                    sX = Mid(sX, 1, (iX - 1))
                 Else
                    sX = ""
                End If
                bX = False
            End If
        End If
    Wend  'endof fixing text
    Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Text: " & sX
    Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Indent Level: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).IndentLevel
    Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Length: ", .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Length)
    Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Start: ", .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Start)
    Print #fileNumber, Space(12) & "Font"
    Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Name: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Name
    Print #fileNumber, Space(20) & "Bold: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Bold
    Print #fileNumber, Space(20) & "Italic: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Italic
    Print #fileNumber, Space(20) & "Size: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Size
    Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(24) & "RGB: ", .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Color.RGB)
    Print #fileNumber, Space(12) & "Format"
    Select Case .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Alignment
        Case ppAlignLeft
            horizAlign = "Left"
        Case ppAlignCenter
            horizAlign = "Center"
        Case ppAlignRight
            horizAlign = "Right"
        Case ppAlignJustify
            horizAlign = "Justify"
        Case Else
            horizAlign = "Unknown"
    End Select
    Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Horizontal Alignment: " & Trim(Str(.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Alignment)) & " (" & horizAlign & "}"
    Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Bullet"
    Print #fileNumber, Space(20) & "Character: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character
    Print #fileNumber, Space(20) & "Font"
    Print #fileNumber, Space(24) & "Name: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Name
    Print #fileNumber, Space(24) & "Bold: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Bold
    Print #fileNumber, Space(28) & "Italic: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Italic
    Print #fileNumber, Space(28) & "Size: " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Size
    Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(24) & "RGB: ", .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Color.RGB)
Next  'endof paragraph (1)
End If  'endof (has) text (1)
End If  'endof text frame existancer
If (.HasTextFrame = True) Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Frame 2"
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Margin Bottom: ", .TextFrame2.MarginBottom)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Margin Left: ", .TextFrame2.MarginLeft)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Margin Right: ", .TextFrame2.MarginRight)
Call PrintPixels(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Margin Top: ", .TextFrame2.MarginTop)
Select Case .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor
Case msoAnchorTop
    vertAlign = "Top"
Case msoAnchorMiddle
    vertAlign = "Middle"
Case msoAnchorBottom
    vertAlign = "Bottom"
Case Else
    vertAlign = "Unknown"
End Select
' Get Horizontal Alignment
Select Case .TextFrame2.HorizontalAnchor
Case ppAlignLeft
    horizAlign = "Left"
Case ppAlignCenter
    horizAlign = "Center"
Case ppAlignRight
    horizAlign = "Right"
Case ppAlignJustify
    horizAlign = "Justify"
Case Else
    horizAlign = "Unknown"
End Select
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Vertical Alignment: " & vertAlign
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Horizontal Alignment: " & horizAlign
If .TextFrame2.HasText = msoTrue Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Text Range"
sX = "(no paragraphs)"
If .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count > 0 Then
    sX = CStr(.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count)
End If
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Paragraphs: " & sX
For lParagraph = 1 To .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
    Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Paragraph: " & CStr(lParagraph) & " < 2<<<<<<<<<<<<"
    Print #fileNumber, Space(12) & "Font"
    Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Name: " & .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Name
    Call PrintTF(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Bold: ", .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Bold)
    Call PrintTF(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Italic: ", .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Italic)
    Print #fileNumber, Space(16) & "Size: " & .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Size
    Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Back RGB: ", .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Fill.BackColor.RGB)
    Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(16) & "Fore RGB: ", .TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs(lParagraph).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB)
Next  'endof a 2 paragraph
End If  'endof (has) text
End If  'endof text there
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Animation"
sX = ShapeEntryEffectNumber(.AnimationSettings.EntryEffect)
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Entry Effect: " & .AnimationSettings.EntryEffect & " (" & sX & ")"
sX = ShapeAfterEffectNumber(.AnimationSettings.AfterEffect)
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "After Effect: " & .AnimationSettings.AfterEffect & " (" & sX & ")"
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Animation Dim: ", .AnimationSettings.DimColor.RGB)
End With  'endof a shape
Next  'endof shapes
End If  'done with shapes
sX = "(no effects)"
If Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count > 0 Then
sX = CStr(Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count)
End If
Print #fileNumber, "Slide Main Sequence Effects: " & sX
lTrigger = 0
If Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count > 0 Then
For lEffect = 1 To Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count
Print #fileNumber, "Effect: " & CStr(lEffect)
With Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence(lEffect)
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Display Name: " & .DisplayName
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Start: " & .TextRangeStart
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Length: " & .TextRangeLength
lTrigger = 0
sX = "No action associated as the trigger found."
If .Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerAfterPrevious Then
lTrigger = 3
sX = "After the Previous button is clicked."
End If
If .Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerMixed Then
lTrigger = -1
sX = "Mixed actions."
End If
If .Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerNone Then
lTrigger = 0
sX = "No action associated as the trigger."
End If
If .Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick Then
lTrigger = 1
sX = "When a page is clicked."
End If
If .Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick Then
lTrigger = 4
sX = "When a shape is clicked."
End If
If .Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious Then
lTrigger = 2
sX = "When the Previous button is clicked."
End If
If .Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerOnMediaBookmark Then
lTrigger = 5
sX = "Bookmark"
End If
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Trigger: " & CInt(lTrigger) & " " & sX
On Error Resume Next
paraNum = .paragraph    ' Retrieve the paragraph number
On Error GoTo 0
sX = "0"
If paraNum > 0 Then
sX = Trim$(Str$(paraNum))
End If
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Effect Paragraph: " & sX
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Shape: " & .shape.Name
sX = AnimActionSettingsNumber(.EffectType)
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Effect Type: " & .EffectType & " (" & sX & ")"
tempVarX = .Exit
sX = "False"
If tempVarX = msoTrue Then
sX = "True"
End If
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Effect Exit: " & sX
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Parameters"
paramType = TypeName(.EffectParameters)
If paramType <> "Nothing" Then
tempVarX = "FontName"
bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .EffectParameters)
If bX = True Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Parameter Font Name: " & tempVarX
End If
tempVarX = "Amount"
bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .EffectParameters)
If bX = True Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Parameter Amount: " & tempVarX
End If
tempVarX = "Color2.RGB"
bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .EffectParameters)
If bX = True Then
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Parameter Color2: ", tempVarX)
End If
tempVarX = "FontSize"
bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .EffectParameters)
If bX = True Then
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Parameter Font Size: " & tempVarX
End If
End If  'endof effect parms
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Information"
paramType = TypeName(.EffectInformation)
If paramType <> "Nothing" Then
tempVarX = "AfterEffect"
bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .EffectInformation)
If bX = True Then
sX = ShapeAfterEffectNumber(tempVarX)
Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Information Effect: " & .EffectInformation.AfterEffect & " (" & sX & ")"
End If
tempVarX = "Dim"
bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .EffectInformation)
If bX = True Then
Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Information Dim: ", tempVarX)
End If
End If  'endof EffectInformation
paramType = TypeName(.Behaviors)
If paramType <> "Nothing" Then
tempVarX = "Count"
bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, .Behaviors)
If bX = True Then
sX = CStr(tempVarX)
Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Behaviors: " & sX
End If
If .Behaviors.Count > 0 Then
For iBehavior = 1 To .Behaviors.Count
    sX = Trim(CStr(iBehavior))
    Print #fileNumber, Space(4) & "Behavior: " & sX
    With Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence(lEffect).Behaviors(iBehavior)
        Set oMyObj = Ppt_Slide.TimeLine.MainSequence(lEffect).Behaviors(iBehavior)
        tempVarX = "Type"
        bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, oMyObj)
        If bX = True Then
            sZ = BehaviorTypeNumber(tempVarX)
            iX = Val(sZ)
            sX = PptGetAnimType(iX)
            Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Behavior Type: " & .Type & " (" & sZ & ")"
        End If
        tempVarX = "PropertyEffect"
        bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, oMyObj)
        If bX = True Then
            Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Behavior Property Effect: " & tempVarX
        End If
        tempVarX = "ColorEffect.From.RGB"
        bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, oMyObj)
        If bX = True Then
            Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Behavior From Color: ", .ColorEffect.From.RGB)
        End If
        tempVarX = "SetEffect.Property"
        bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, oMyObj)
        If bX = True Then
            sX = PptGetAnimProperty(tempVarX)
            Print #fileNumber, Space(8) & "Behavior Set Effect Property: " & tempVarX & " (" & sX & "}"
            If tempVarX = "101" Then
                tempVarX = "SetEffect.To"
                bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, oMyObj)
                If bX = True Then
                    Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Behavior Set Effect To Color: ", tempVarX)
                End If  'endof found color
            End If  'endof 101
        End If  'endof found property
        tempVarX = "ColorEffect.To.RGB"
        bX = GetEffectParameters(tempVarX, oMyObj)
        If bX = True Then
            Call ColorToRGB(fileNumber, Space(8) & "Behavior To Color: ", tempVarX)
        End If
    End With  'endof a behavior
Next  'endof behaviors
End If  'endof all behaviors
End If
End With
Next  'end or an effect
End If  'endof effects
Next slideCurrent  'done with slides

Close #fileNumber  'endof output

MsgBox "Slide attributes written to " & filePath

End Sub

Slides: 15
key: [00000099200200000000sldc 0000] value: [1]
======== NEW SLIDE =====================
Slide: 1
Slide ID: 448
Slide Name: Slide193
Slide Number: 1
Slide Width:  960 (13.3333)[1280]
Slide Height:  540 (7.5)[720]
slide Foreground Fill:  15717476 {rgb(100, 212, 239)} [bkgrndcyan]
Slide Background Fill:  9328646 {rgb(6, 88, 142)} [darkblue]
Slide Interactive Sequences: 0
Slide Shapes: 1
Shape: 1
    Shape ID: 3
    Shape Name: TextBox 2
    Shape Title: 
    Shape   Type: 17 (TextBox)
    Visible: True
    Shape Background: Color:  16777215 {rgb(255, 255, 255)} [white]
    Shape Foreground Color:  16777215 {rgb(255, 255, 255)} [white]
    Shape  Width:  117 (1.625)[156]
    Shape Height:  24 (.3333)[32]
    Shape   Left:  51 (.7083)[68]
    Shape    Top:  62 (.8611)[82.6667]
    Font
        Font Name: Century Gothic
        Text Hello There
        Font is Bold
        Font Size: 14
    Frame 1
        Top Margin:  4 (.0556)[5.3333]
        Right Margin:  7 (.0972)[9.3333]
        Bottom Margin:  4 (.0556)[5.3333]
        Left Margin:  7 (.0972)[9.3333]
        Horizontal Alignment: 1 (Left}
        Text Range
                Range Text: Hello There  
                Range Start: 1
                Range Length: 13
            Font
                Font Name: Century Gothic
                Bold: True
                Italic: False
                Size 14
                Color:  10498160 {rgb(112, 48, 160)} [purple]
        Paragraphs: 1
        Paragraph: 1 < 1<<<<<<<<<<<<
                Text: Hello There  
                Indent Level: 1
                Length:  13 (.1806)[17.3333]
                Start:  1 (.0139)[1.3333]
            Font
                Name: Century Gothic
                    Bold: -1
                    Italic: 0
                    Size: 14
                        RGB:  10498160 {rgb(112, 48, 160)} [purple]
            Format
                Horizontal Alignment: 1 (Left}
                Bullet
                    Character: 8226
                    Font
                        Name: 
                        Bold: -1
                            Italic: 0
                            Size: 14
                        RGB:  0 {rgb(0, 0, 0)} [black]
    Frame 2
        Margin Bottom:  4 (.0556)[5.3333]
        Margin Left:  7 (.0972)[9.3333]
        Margin Right:  7 (.0972)[9.3333]
        Margin Top:  4 (.0556)[5.3333]
        Vertical Alignment: Top
        Horizontal Alignment: Left
        Text Range
        Paragraphs: 1
        Paragraph: 1 < 2<<<<<<<<<<<<
            Font
                Name: Century Gothic
                Bold: True
                Italic: False
                Size: 14
                Back RGB:  16777215 {rgb(255, 255, 255)} [white]
                Fore RGB:  10498160 {rgb(112, 48, 160)} [purple]
    Animation
        Entry Effect: 257 (Cut)
        After Effect: 0 (No effect)
        Animation Dim:  9792053 {rgb(53, 106, 149)} [darkerblue]
Slide Main Sequence Effects: 1
Effect: 1
    Display Name: Hello There   
    Start: 0
    Length: 14
    Trigger: 1 When a page is clicked.
    Effect Paragraph: 1
    Shape: TextBox 2
    Effect Type: 56 (Font Color Changes)
        Effect Exit: False
    Parameters
        Parameter Color2:  65280 {rgb(0, 255, 0)} [green]
    Information
        Information Effect: 1 (Hides)
        Information Dim:  9792053 {rgb(53, 106, 149)} [darkerblue]
    Behaviors: 1
    Behavior: 1
        Behavior Type: 8 (Set)
        Behavior Set Effect Property: 101 (Text font color}
        Behavior Set Effect To Color:  65280 {rgb(0, 255, 0)} [green]

and here is the problem:  Dim is reported as darker blue
"Information Dim:  9792053 {rgb(53, 106, 149)} [darkerblue]"
I don't know why Dim isn't being reported as yellow and I do not know where the darker blue is coming from.

Your code is quite long. Can you please create a minimal reproducible example?
